# Sphinx Read-The-Docs Theme recognised but not "found"

Tags: themes, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I downloaded the read-the-docs theme for sphinx from Github and put it into the _themes folder.

**conf.py:**

```
html_theme = "sphinx_rtd_theme"
html_theme_path = ["_themes", ]
```

However, running "make html" I get this error:

```
Sphinx v4.1.2 in Verwendung
Lade Übersetzungen [de]…erledigt
loading pickled environment... erledigt
WARNING: sphinx_rtd_theme (< 0.3.0) found. It will not be available since Sphinx-6.0

Theme error:
no theme named 'sphinx_rtd_theme' found (missing theme.conf?)
```

Somehow Sphinx seems to find the theme and then disregard it. Can someone tell me what is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: I think you should _install_ the theme using "pip install sphinx-rtd-theme" (https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-rtd-theme/)

Comment: That's right then it works. But I have another problem with templates in the _templates folder that don't trigger with the global theme installation via ´pip install sphinx-rtd-theme´

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "trigger with the global theme installation".

Comment: @mzjn sorry, solved. I created the _templates folder at the wrong hierarchical level... To get back to the original question: Is the way via git repo not supported anymore then?

Comment: Has it ever been supported to do it by downloading from GitHub?

Comment: Yes apparently but it says it's deprecated (look at the bottom) https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing.html

Answer (score 26):

Need to install:

```
pip install sphinx-rtd-theme
```

Comment: this text coul be provided as a comment instead of a full answer

Comment: I do have `sphinx-rtd-theme` installed and still does not work.

Comment: @SomeDev Don't know if this helps, but I'm on an M1 and had the same issue. It's installed, pip throws "Requirement already satisfied" when trying to install it.

I got around it by commenting out the 'html_theme = "sphinx_rtd_theme"' from the conf.py file. Not sure what the impact is, but the HTML generated ok for me after that.

Answer (score 11):

**I solved it!** (not the same as OP, since he did not have the package installed, but maybe it'll be useful for somebody)

If it doesn't work for you, be `sure to use underscores` in the `conf.py` file as the package uses normal dashes.

In `conf.py` it should be like this
`html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'`
not like this
`html_theme = 'sphinx-rtd-theme'`

https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-rtd-theme/

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using a requirements.txt file, which I used to install the sphinx_rtd_theme module. Follow the steps mentioned, and I assume you have a GitHub repo connected with readthedocs server.

1. Add the following lines in your .ymal file

> ```
> python:
>    install:
>      - requirements: docs/requirements.txt
> ```

2. Now place a requirements.txt file in the location specified above with the following text

   sphinx-rtd-theme
3. Add, commit and push the changes to the origin and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the underscore point mentioned by Some Dev, but I also needed to update `pip` to the latest version:

```bash
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Please wrap command text using backticks https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans